# Community for Medical Devices

Tags: discussion

I work in a medical device manufacturing company. I work in Regulatory and QA. Is there a Stack Exchange community for medical device manufacturing/ or Medical device Regulatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. The closest would be Engineering and Electrical Engineering.

Comment: Thank you Carey!

Comment: @Vrij The whole list is at https://stackexchange.com/sites#users - there are several others that might come up as relevant within specific areas of the categories you mention. Be sure to visit the Help page like https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic on each site to see what belongs there.